# program is compiling even without implementing the interface

Tags: java

I have an interface named `abc`

```
public interface abc
{
    void start();
}
```

and I have an abstract class named `def`

```
public abstract class def extends Thread implements abc
{
}
```

I created another class that extends `def` called `ghj`

```
public class ghj extends def
{
  //it is defing all the methods of its above abstract class
  //now it does not implement the method define in interface start();
}
```

Please advise if the  class `ghj` does not implement the interface `abc` required methods then how can the program be compiling?

Answer (score 14):

Although you are not directly defining `start()`, by extending `Thread`, an implementation of [`start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) is being provided to `def` and its subclasses, therefore fulfilling the contract of the `abc` interface.

Comment: yes and what if we change the return type of start but still extend thread will it be compile time error

Comment: @anshulkatta If you change the return type of `start()` in the interface, the code will not compile due to incompatible return types between the method contract (given by the interface) and the provided method (defined in Thread).

Comment: @Downvoter, I'm curious as to why you have downvoted my answer. Please explain.

Comment: @anshulkatta You can overload it if the method declaration differs; it would need a different name and/or signature.

Comment: @Vulcan different name ?? , i think void start(String s), or  as many any  argument will do the overload

Comment: @anshulkatta Indeed, that is correct, which is why I said name *and/or signature*. A method's signature is its return type and argument types.

Answer (score 2):

Your full class is already inheriting `start()` method from `Thread` class which is having exactly the same signature. That's why compiler is not generating any error.

Comment: hellooww !! it is start() -_-